# proceed if argument is not given manually

Tags: python, unix

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time

date = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
if date ==5 or date ==6:
 print "Its saturday or sunday: exiting"
 exit()

if sys.argv[0]:  #Going Back one Day
 date = datetime.date.today()
 yday = date-timedelta(days=1)
 mm = date.strftime("%b")
 yyyy= str(yday.year)
 dd =  '%02d' % yday.day

#Arguments If Needed
elif sys.argv[1]:
 dd=sys.argv[1][0:2]
 mm=sys.argv[1][2:5]
 yyyy=sys.argv[1][5:9]


date=dd+"-"+mm+"-"+yyyy
print date
```

This code works properly if no system argument is given manually
But when argument is given of an earlier date, it still prints the prev date.

I cant put my finger on what is going wrong
Please do help Thanks!

if i run the code, (`python a.py`) it prints `06-Dec-2015`
but if i give an argument,lets say (`python a.py 01-Dec-2015`) it still prints `06-Dec-2015`

Comment: can you please add an example where it fails

Comment: i hope the edit helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` statement is wrong. You're checking for `sys.argv[0]` (i.e. the name of your script), which will usually evaluate to `True` (because it contains an actual string). The `elif` part will never be triggered.

Instead, check for the number of arguments as follows:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    # No arguments (except for the script name)
    # ...
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # 1 argument
    # ...
```